# VHost subdomain redirect

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vhosts

I've found a VHost rule for redirecting blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog, however in my case, blog.domain.com redirects to domain.com/blog/**html**.

This is my /sites-availabe/blog.domain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.domain.com
    Redirect "/" "http://domain.com/blog"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have an **A** record redirecting blog.domain.com to domain.com.

EDIT: added http:// to the Redirect-rule. Now, when entering blog.domain.com, you get redirected to domain.com, but the URL is masked to blog.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URLs need to start with the scheme.

```
Redirect / http://domain.com/blog/
```

Comment: Thank you! This stopped it from redirecting to **domain.com/blog/html**, however it now enters **domain.com/** and masks the URL to **blog.domain.com**. I've updated the post accordingly to this suggestion.

Comment: @AdamEnderdal — That's what redirecting is supposed to do. If you want keep the URL in the address bar then you'll need to use a frame or a proxy.

Comment: I want the content of **domain.com/blog** to be displayed when entering **blog.domain.com** into the address-bar. If the URL then displays **blog.domain.com** or **domain.com/blog** doesn't really matter.

I just want domain.com/blog and blog.domain.com to land on the same page.